# How do I get my JTextFields to line up correctly under a title?

Tags: user-interface, jpanel, jtextfield, flowlayout

This is what it should look like

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;   
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;   

import javax.swing.*;

public class UI extends JFrame
 {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private JPanel topPanel;
   private JPanel mainPanel;
   private JPanel botPanel;
   private JLabel message;
   private JTextField total, total1, total2, total3, total4, total5;
   private JTextField score, score1, score2, score3, score4,score5;
   private final int width = 650;       
   private final int height = 400;  

 public UI()
 {
    setTitle("Desert Soccer League");
    setSize(width,height);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    buildTop();
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    buildMain();
    add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buildBot();
    add(botPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

private void buildTop()
{
    topPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    message = new JLabel("2014 Desert Soccer League");
    topPanel.add(message);
}

private void buildMain()
{
    mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(0,100,20));
    JLabel team = new JLabel("Teams");
    JLabel points = new JLabel("Total Points");
    JLabel winLoss = new JLabel("Win-Loss-Tie");
    JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
    t.setText("Arabian");
    t.setEnabled(false);
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    t1.setText("Gobi");
    t1.setEnabled(false);
    JTextField t2 = new JTextField(10);
    t2.setText("Outback");
    t2.setEnabled(false);
    JTextField t3 = new JTextField(10);
    t3.setText("Patagonian");
    t3.setEnabled(false);
    JTextField t4 = new JTextField(10);
    t4.setText("Sahara");
    t4.setEnabled(false);
    JTextField t5 = new JTextField(10);
    t5.setText("Sonoran");
    t5.setEnabled(false);

    mainPanel.add(team);
    mainPanel.add(points);
    mainPanel.add(winLoss);
    mainPanel.add(t);
    mainPanel.add(t1);
    mainPanel.add(t2);
    mainPanel.add(t3);
    mainPanel.add(t4);
    mainPanel.add(t5);
}

private void buildBot()
{
    botPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JButton io = new JButton("Read Input File");
    io.setActionCommand("I");
    io.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    JButton calc = new JButton("Calculate Points");
    calc.setActionCommand("C");
    calc.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    JButton champ = new JButton("Championship Winner");
    champ.setActionCommand("O");
    champ.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    JButton second = new JButton("Earth Cup Wiiner");
    second.setActionCommand("T");
    second.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
    JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
    exit.setActionCommand("E");
    exit.addActionListener(new ButtonListener5());

    botPanel.add(io);
    botPanel.add(calc);
    botPanel.add(champ);
    botPanel.add(second);
    botPanel.add(exit);
}

private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
         if(e.getActionCommand() == "I")
         {
             JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the path and the name of the file");
         }
      }
}

private class ButtonListener5 implements ActionListener
{
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      {
          if(e.getActionCommand() == "E")   
            {
                System.exit(0); 
            }

      }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    UI frame = new UI();
    frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

I'm having trouble lining up my textfileds under the JLabel Teams. Can someone help me line up my first row of text fields like the example above. I've tried GridLayout as well but it doesn't seem to work the way I would like it and the since it resizes itself automatically it looks unappealing. Also because this is a class project I can only use what I have been taught so the only Layouts we have learned are BorderLayout, FlowLayout, and GridLayout. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Put the labels in the grid, not in a separate panel above the grid.